# GWT access file within WebContent

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt, servlets, glassfish

I am trying to send a folder's content as `String[]` but I have some problem with paths. In hosted mode the following code works fine:

```
File dir= new File("folder-in-webcontents-dir");    
String contents=dir.list();    
return contents;
```

This snippet is executed in the server side implementation of an RPC call.
When this project is deployed in glassfish after using logging I see that  `.getabsolutefilepath()` 
returns something like `c:\glassfish\glassfish\domains\domain1\CONFIG(??)\folder-in-webcontents-dir`.

How can I then point to this specific folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code on the server side (on your RPC)

```
String URL = getServletContext().getRealPath("/folder-in-webcontents-dir");
File dir = new File(URL);
return dir.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
File file = new File("/folder-in-webcontents-dir");
String contents=dir.list();    
Return contents;
```